# How can I extract data from multiple files in a folder of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 140 excel files in a folder that have the same identical format, and in each file have a sheet name called “data” (which is hidden) where I have information range c2:c12. I need a macro to extract all the data from these 140 excel files in a folder and should be pasted in my summary sheet in row wise. (the information extracted from C2toC12, has to transpose) each file information should be pasted row wise.

Example: C2 = File Name, C3=Name,C4=Father Name,C5=Age and etc.. upto C12

All the extracted information should be pasted into my summary sheet with transpose (row wise)

Note: while extracting the data, I have already the path from where it has to extract and which is in my summary sheet “E1”

Any help in pointing me in the right direction here would be most appreciated

Comment: If you are using Excel 2010 or 2013 you should download and enable Power Query. It is perfect for this sort of task.

Comment: Sir, can you elaborate it. I am hearing first time about this "power Query"

Comment: This link has an example: http://www.databasejournal.com/sqletc/getting-started-with-microsoft-power-query-for-excel.html. I would encourage you to do a transform with one Excel sheet first ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FileSystemObject to get all the name of the files you need. and then do want you want in a loop

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim xlWb As Workbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("your\folder")

for each file in folder.files
  Set xlWb = Workbooks.Open(file.Path & "\" & file.Name)
  'your code here
  xlWb.Close
next
```

Comment: Sir, can you please share me the remaining codes for loop, so that I can directly copy paste the same in my Summary workbook

Comment: Sorry, but no. I am not going to do your whole job. This site is to ask for help. Not to outsource your work.