# For analysis of test data

Tags: excel, vba

Have about 2000 files of text information each file having 20000+ lines and 8 columns. Each files has to be read for a calculation and closes and the result of the calculation has to be stored in Excel.

Comment: **We understand your assignment...what is your question ??**

Comment: Please provide the code of what you've already tried, otherwise we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so vague, I do not understand what sort of answer you expected.

For example:

- are all 2000 files in the same folder,
- do they have particular names,
- do they have to be processed in a particular sequence,
- how are the rows within the files divided into columns,
- what calculations are required,
- how are results to be stored?

Do not come back with answers to these questions.  This site does not provide a free coding service.  Instead split your requirement into little steps and look for help with each step.

Step 1 will be to find the 2000 files.  The last related question (see on the right) is [How can I extract data from multiple files in a folder of excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31766195/973283) which shows how to find every file in a folder and open it as a workbook.  That code is probably the outline structure for your macro.  You will have to look up `GetFolder` to find the exact syntax but that is not too difficult.

Try to develop the macro you require.  Come here with specific problems and code that does not function as you wish and you will find people who will help.